# Get Backbone PUT file in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, file, backbone.js, put

I have a form with text and file input and I use Backbone and Backbone-model-file-upload to send data on my server. It's work when I send POST request :

```
var file = $('#logo')[0].files[0];
var formData = $(e.currentTarget).serializeObject();

var unClient = new ClientModel();
unClient.set({
    pseudo : formData['pseudo'],
    'logo' : file,
    password: formData['password'],
    username : formData['username']
});
unClient.save(null, {
    success: function(){
        //Window location
    },
    error: function(){
        //box error
    }
});
```

With 'logo' in fileAttribute.
I get my data with $_POST and file_get_contents($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name']) for file
But with PUT request, I can't read data file :

```
unClient.set({
    id : id,
    pseudo: formData['pseudo'],
    'logo' : file,
    password : formDate['password'],
    username : formData['username']
});
unClient.save(null, {
    success: function(){
        //redirection
    },
    error: function(){
        //bootbooxErreur
    }
});
```

To get PUT request I tried :

```
file_get_contents("php://input");
```

or:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

And for file :

```
file_get_contents($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name']);
```

But it's doesn't work

Comment: I don't think you can use `file_get_contents` on the `php://input` stream - you should use `fopen` instead. See this PHP.net page for info about file upload with http PUT - http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php